# How to evaluate the single turnstile symbol ($\vdash$) in propositional logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols) says, that:

> $x \vdash y$ means y is provable from x (in some specified formal system).

But what do you actually check *or calculate*, when you have $(a \land \lnot b) \vdash a$? Has $(a \land \lnot b)$ to be true for at least all combinations of a and b whenever $a$ is true or does this belong to the double turnstile symbol ($\vDash$)?

Answer (score 3):

The "turnstile" symbol, used in the context $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$, means that, *relative to the proof system we are working with*, there is a *derivation* of the formula $\varphi$ from the formulae in $\Gamma$ with the *rules* and *logical axioms* of the *proof system*.

In the *Natural Deduction* proof system, we can build-up this simple derivation :

1) $a \land \lnot b$ --- premise

2) $a$ --- from 1) by [Conjunction elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination)

showing that : $a \land \lnot b \vdash a$.

If the proof system is *complete*, i.e. if the *Completeness Theorem* saying that :

> if $\Gamma \vDash \varphi$, then $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$

applies, as is the case for the "usual" *proof systems* for *propositional* and *first-order* logic, like *Natural Deduction*, we can take benefit of it proving *deducibility* from *(tauto)logical consequence*.

In *propositional logic* we can show that :

> $a \land \lnot b \vDash a$;

with truth-table or through the definition of *(tauto)logical consequence*, i.e. the *conclusion* : $a$ must be *true* for any truth assignment that satisfy the *premise* : $a \land \lnot b$.

Having done this, we can use the *completeness* of propositional logic to conclude that there is a *derivation* of $a$ from $a \land \lnot b$, i.e. that :

> $a \land \lnot b \vdash a$.